# Multi Upload In Theme Options

Tags: uploads, media-library

I need to use the WordPress media upload on a theme options page. It needs to be able to have multiple fields on one page. I have seen a few things on the site using search but nothing recent and nothing i can get to work.

Can someone please show me an easy way to do this.

Would really like to use the new gallery style where you pick a picture from the media gallery, or choose to upload.

Comment: Could you enumerate what have you tried and how a bit? It would be a waste for people to look up and suggest things that have already not worked out for you.

Answer (score -2):

Check [this link](http://www.thecreatology.com/add-multiple-image-upload-button-using-wordpress-uploader-in-theme.html). I hope this may help you.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a comment and not an answer. Answers should never rely on external links. Please file an [edit] and add all relevant info directly to your answer